# Do we need to set width attribute for each cell in HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

How does different browser use the Width attribute of Cells in a table?

I am using Tables extensively in my application and mostly use Fixed layout, with all columns given a specified width.

What I am interested to know is, do we need to specify width for cell in each rows? or is it enough if we do that in the table header and not specify anything in the table body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use fixed table layout in the technical sense, i.e. have the CSS declaration `table-layout: fixed`, then the first row determines the column widths and any width settings for cells in other rows will be ignored. (This may result in truncation of cell contexts—that’s part of the idea of fixed layout.)

Otherwise, the width requirements of all cells are taken into account by the browser when it calculates column widths. So if you have `width=100` in a cell in the header row but another cell in the same content has content that requires 200 pixels at the minimum, that width will be used and your setting for the first-row cell will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the `width` attribute once per column should be sufficient in most cases. It doesn't even need to be specified in the first row, as long as it's specified in a subsequent row.

Here's a simple [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Trx/1/).